# Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, lodash

How can I write this code in more elegant way. I have looked on lodash etc. but couldn't actually find the best way to destructure object for my needs.
Because I will write those properties on mongo I also tried to verify if they are exist or not.

```
 const { _id, name, bio, birth_date, photos, instagram, gender, jobs, schools } = element
    let myPhotos = photos.map((photo) => photo.id)
    let insta = {}
    if (instagram) {
        insta.mediaCount = instagram.media_count
        insta.profilePicture = instagram.profile_picture
        insta.username = instagram.username
        insta.photos = instagram.photos.map((photo) => photo.image)
    }

    const doc = {}

    doc._id = ObjectId(_id)
    doc.name = name
    doc.birthDate = new Date(birth_date)

    if (bio.length) {
        doc.bio = bio
    }
    if (myPhotos.length) {
        doc.photos = myPhotos
    }
    if (Object.keys(insta).length) {
        doc.instagram = insta
    }
    doc.gender = gender

    if (jobs.length) {
        doc.jobs = jobs
    }

    if (schools.length) {
        doc.schools = schools
    }

    try {
        await collection.insertOne(doc)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("err", error)
    }
```

Comment: What is actually in `element`? The very first line is breaking up the object and then all you are doing is "putting it back together". There are probably ways you "destructure" by "removal" of unnecessary items, but this "probably" should be done from the perspective of seeing what the "source" actually is to begin with. It's a better question if you describe the source.

Comment: element is actually json response and i only need properties i specified but whole code goes into mess

Comment: You're being asked to actually show a data sample here. Point being it's probably better to "exclude" fields rather than explicitly "include". Just show a sample.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i am not sure about that because i think there's a lack of knowledge on map,filter,reduce or lodash methods. That's why i posted here, do i think wrong?

Comment: @BatuG. - you have not identified your needs per: _destructure object for my needs_ - Please identify what your needs are and provide input and expected outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the `doc` all at once using the ternary operator to test conditions. If the `undefined` properties need to be removed, then you can remove them via `reduce` afterward.

```
const { _id, name, bio, birth_date, photos, instagram, gender, jobs, schools } = element
const myPhotos = photos.map(({ id }) => id)
const insta = !instagram ? undefined : (() => {
  const { media_count, profile_picture, username, photos } = instagram;
  return {
    mediaCount: media_count,
    profilePicture: profile_picture,
    username,
    photos: photos.map(({ image }) => image)
  }
})();
const docWithUndef = {
  _id: ObjectId(_id),
  name,
  gender,
  birthDate: new Date(birth_date),
  bio: bio.length ? bio : undefined,
  photos: myPhotos.length ? myPhotos : undefined,
  instagram: insta,
  jobs: jobs.length ? jobs : undefined,
  schools: schools.length ? schools : undefined,
}
const doc = Object.entries(docWithUndef)
.reduce((accum, [key, val]) => {
  if (val !== undefined) accum[key] = val;
  return accum;
});
try {
  await collection.insertOne(doc)
} catch (error) {
  console.log("err", error)
}
```

Note the destructuring of the *arguments* to reduce the syntax noise, and the use of `const` rather than `let` (improves code readability).

Comment: `MongoClient.connect(url, {ignoreUndefined:true})` might be helpful here.